# How to find the closest element to a given binary key value using binary search algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I have a sorted list of binary vectors, let's call it L, and I have a binary vector q, how can I find the vectors in L that are closest to q using binary search?

Comment: how do you define closest. Is it the distance between two vectors.

Comment: He probably means the Hamming distance.

Comment: have you tried looking at wikipedia in the "closest distance" algorithms pages?

Answer (score 1):

In case you define the closest as the distance between two vectors. here is the pesudo code to to find the vector that is closest.

```
Vector closestVector = null;
Vector findClosestVector(L,q)
{

     int i= L.lenght/2;
     if(i ==1 ) 
     {
           Vector v = L.get(0);
           int distance = distance(v,q);
           if(closestVector == null)
           {
                   closestVector = v;
           }
           else {
               int d1 = distance(closestVector,q);
               if(d1 > distance) {
                     closestVector = v;
                     return v;
                 }
           }

     }
     else
     {
           Vector left = findClosestVector(L(0,L/2),q);
           Vector right = findClosestVector(L(L/2,L),q);
           if(distance(left,q) > distance(right,q))
           {
                return right;
           }
           else
           {
               return left;
           }
     }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you have a sorted list of vectors, I assume that by "closest" you mean vectors that are closest to another with respect to that ordering. You can use [`java.util.Arrays.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for that. It returns:

> index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (- *insertion point* - 1). The *insertion point* is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array.

So if the vector `q` is in the array, you find its index and its neighbours are closest to it. If it isn't, you'll find an index `j = -i - 1` (`i` is the result of `binarySearch`) where `q` would be inserted and then `i` and `i-1` would be the closest to it.